# The space $C[0,1]$ is path connected.

Tags: general-topology, connectedness, topological-vector-spaces

I have a proof of the statement. Can you please let me know where did I go wrong?

The space $C[0,1]$ is path connected. Proof: Let $f,g\in C[0,1].$ Define

$T:[0,1] \to C[0,1]$   s.t $T(t) = f(x) +t(f(x) - g(x))$
so $T(t) \in C[0,1]$

NOW I will show $T(t)$ is continuous.when  $t_n \to t$   , $T(t_n) \to T(t)$ as $||T(t_n) - T(t)|| \leq |t_n - t|.||(f(x) - g(x) )||$.(It is possible because $[0,1]$ is haudroff space).

That's how $C[0,1]$ is path connected.

Please mention where I went wrong.

Comment: The space is stable under linear combinations, hence convex, hence path-connected.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/643886/a-proof-that-c0-1-is-separable is saying separable..

Comment: Any normed linear space is path connected.

Comment: That $[0,1]$ is Hausdorff is not used in your estimate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with it. The definition of $T$ is redundant (if you define $T(t)=f(x)+t\bigl(g(x)-f(x)\bigr)$, there is no need to say that $T(0)=f(x)$ and that $T(1)=g(x)$), but that is not a logical error.

Comment: Edited..But https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/643886/a-proof-that-c0-1-is-separable is saying $c[0,1]$ is separable.

Comment: 'Separable' isn't the opposite of 'connected'. A space can be both connected and separable at the same time.

Comment: @cmi Separable just means that it has a countable dense subset.

Comment: Can You please elaborate because we were first given the definition of separation and then told whichever set does not have separation is called connected ?@AymanHourieh

Comment: @cmi My guess is that when the concept of connectedness was explained to you, your teach explained that “connected” means that the whole set is together, in one piece.