# Continuous operators on $C[0,1] $ are not separable

Tags: functional-analysis, separable-spaces

Taking class in functional analysis, I was told that continuous operators $$A:C[0,1]\rightarrow C[0,1]$$ are **not separable**. I'm trying to prove it by finding **uncountable** family of operators $A_\alpha$ such that $$\forall  A_1, A_2\in A_\alpha \ \ \ \ \|A_1-A_2\|= \sup\limits_{\|f\|\le 1} \|(A_1-A_2)f\|>\varepsilon$$
where $\varepsilon$ is fixed. Operators of multiplying by constant totally does not make sense, I thought about multiplying by function, but  didn't figure it out. So, currently I'm fighting with an example of such family of operators, any hint appreciated!

Comment: Multiplying by $C[0,1]$ function will not work since $C[0,1]$ is separable and we can use this to express the multiplication operator: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/643886/a-proof-that-c0-1-is-separable

Comment: Saw the answers. An interesting thought: Define the sequence: $s_f = \{f(q):q \in \mathbb{Q} \cap [0,1]\}$. Since $f$ is continuous, $s_f$ completely characterizes $f$. So the space of operators can be viewed as operators mapping a sequence to another sequence. This is not separable. But if we say restrict to $\ell_2$ converging sequences (similar to functions in $C[0,1]$ with same end points (fourier series maps this space to converging $\ell_2$ sequences)). Can we prove that operators on this $\ell_2$ sequence space is separable ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For $t \in [0,1]$ define $A_t : C([0,1]) \to C([0,1])$ as
$$(A_t f)(x) = f(t)x, \qquad f \in C([0,1]).$$
Then $A_t$ is clearly bounded with $\|A_t\| = 1.$

For $s,t \in [0,1], s <t$ consider $f \in C([0,1])$ given by
$$f(x) =
\begin{cases}
0, &\text{ if } x \in [0,s],\\
\frac{x-s}{t-s}, &\text{ if } x \in [s,t],\\
1, &\text{ if } x \in [t,1].\\
\end{cases}$$ Then we have $$\|A_t-A_s\| \ge \frac{\|(f(t)-f(s))x\|_\infty}{\|f\|_\infty} = 1.$$

Answer (score 3):

**This is an idea**.

Take for example
$$A_\alpha f(x):=\mathbf 1_{[0,\alpha]}(x)f(x),$$
for $\alpha\in(0,1)$, so it is an uncountable family. This is not technically correct, however, because $A_\alpha f$ is not continuous.

Is there a way to make this example work? I don't know

Answer (score 2):

For $0\le x\le 1$ let $$A_xf=f(x)1$$ where $1$ denotes the constant function.
Then $\|A_x\|=1$ and $$\|A_x-A_y\|=2,\quad x\neq y$$ as there is a function (piecewise linear, at most $3$ segments) $f_{x,y}\in C[0,1]$ such that $\|f_{x,y}\|_\infty =1$ and $f_{x,y}(x)=-1,$ $f_{x,y}(y)=1.$

**Remark** The main reason for the lack of separability  is that the dual space of $C[0,1]$ is not separable. Point evaluations are elements of the dual space.

Comment: I liked the final remark.